# wifi doesn't work

Tags: wireless

I have a desktop pc running ubuntu server 16.04 lts, and a laptop running the same os. I can see my server from the laptop but when the ethernet cable is plugged in, my wifi doesn't work. If I unplug the cat5 cable wifi works fine. I am connecting the computers with a router switch.

Comment: How do you notice the wifi doesn't work? What's the problem?

Comment: When the cat5 is plugged in and I use firefox, I can not connect to any website. When I unplug the cat5 cable I can access any web site I want.

Comment: What is the difference between "the ethernet cable" and "the cat5 cable"?

Comment: there is no difference. just two ways of describing the same network cable

Comment: I think what I might need to do is set a higher priorty for the wifi than the ethernet cable has. When I plug in the cable it tries to find internet over the wired connection. I think  lol

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting.html